# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+a+a^2+a^3+ ...a^n)$ for $|a|<1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+a+a^2+a^3+ ...a^n)$ for $|a|<1$. What is the limit if $|a|\ge1$?

Can anyone please explain how to solve this? Just a few hints will suffice thanks.

Comment: Search for 'geometric series'.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, but I can't find it out.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :**
$$1+a+...+a^n=\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$$

Comment: Yes we get that from the sum of the geometric series but i don't know how to solve it further. So will the limit be $\frac{1}{1-a}$?

Comment: Yes. How much work one has to do to show that $a^{n+1}$ has limit $0$ is course-dependent. At one extreme one could take it as obvious. Or else one can do a manipulation using logs. Or else, in a course in analysis, one would let $|a|=\frac{1}{1+t}$ and use the Binomial Theorem, or the Bernoulli Inequality, to show that $(1+t)^n\ge 1+nt$.

Comment: Can you explain the last bit? The one regarding bernoulli inequality?

Comment: @Paradox101: You can also prove it directly without the Binomial Theorem or Bernoulii Inequality. Suppose $|a| < 1$. Then an easy induction shows that the sequence $x_n = |a|^n$ is monotonically decreasing. Since the sequence is also bounded below (by zero), it has a limit, call it $L$. Then $$|a|L  = |a|\lim_{n \to \infty}|a|^n = \lim_{n \to \infty} |a|^{n+1} = \lim_{n \to\infty} |a|^n = L$$
Therefore, $L(|a|-1) = 0$. Since $|a| \neq 1$, this forces $L = 0$. Therefore $\lim_{n \to\infty}|a|^n = 0$, which implies that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a^n = 0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas what about the answer to the next part will the limit be 0 if $a$ is greater than 1?

Comment: When $|a|\ge 1$ I would say the limit does not exist.  (Some people would say that the limit is $\infty$ if $a\ge 1$, and does not exist if $a\le -1$.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

There is a formula for $$1+a+a^2+\dots + a^n$$

and it looks something like $\frac{f(a)}{g(a)}$ where $f$ and $g$ are simple functions of $a$.